# Require XPATH to identify Elements in a DIV and click Checkboxes against them

Tags: xpath

I require to click the Element based on a given criteria.
This is how my SOURCE looks like:

```
<div class="oxd-table-card" data-v-f2168256="" style="">
  <div class="oxd-table-row oxd-table-row--with-border" role="row" data-v-0d5ef602="" data-v-f2168256="" style="">
    <div class="oxd-table-cell oxd-padding-cell" role="cell" style="">
      <div class="oxd-table-card-cell-checkbox">
        <div class="oxd-checkbox-wrapper" data-v-6179b72a="" style="">
          <label class="" data-v-6179b72a="">
            <!---->
            <input type="checkbox" value="0" data-v-6179b72a=""/>
            <span class="oxd-checkbox-input oxd-checkbox-input--active --label-right oxd-checkbox-input" data-v-6179b72a="">
              <i class="oxd-icon bi-check oxd-checkbox-input-icon" data-v-bddebfba="" data-v-6179b72a=""/>
            </span>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="oxd-table-cell oxd-padding-cell" role="cell" style="flex: 1 1 0%;">
      <div data-v-6c07a142="">25-07-2022 (09:00 - 13:00) Half Day </div>
    </div>
    <div class="oxd-table-cell oxd-padding-cell" role="cell" style="flex: 1 1 0%;">
      <div data-v-6c07a142="">Anthony Nolan </div>
    </div>
    <div class="oxd-table-cell oxd-padding-cell" role="cell" style="flex: 1 1 0%;">
      <div data-v-6c07a142="">CAN - Personal </div>
    </div>
    <div class="oxd-table-cell oxd-padding-cell" role="cell" style="flex: 1 1 0%;">
      <div data-v-6c07a142="">12.50 </div>
    </div>
    <div class="oxd-table-cell oxd-padding-cell" role="cell" style="flex: 1 1 0%;">
      <div data-v-6c07a142="">0.50 </div>
    </div>
    <div class="oxd-table-cell oxd-padding-cell" role="cell" style="flex: 1 1 0%;">
      <div data-v-6c07a142="">Pending Approval (0.50) </div>
    </div>
    <div class="oxd-table-cell oxd-padding-cell" role="cell" style="flex: 1 1 5%;">
      <div data-v-6c07a142=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="oxd-table-cell oxd-padding-cell" role="cell" style="flex: 1 1 20%;">
      <div class="oxd-table-cell-actions" data-v-c423d1fa="">
        <button type="button" class="oxd-button oxd-button--medium oxd-button--label-success oxd-table-cell-action-space" data-v-10d463b7="" data-v-c423d1fa="">
          <!----> Approve <!----> </button>
        <button type="button" class="oxd-button oxd-button--medium oxd-button--label-danger oxd-table-cell-action-space" data-v-10d463b7="" data-v-c423d1fa="">
          <!----> Reject <!----> </button>
        <li class="oxd-table-dropdown oxd-table-cell-action-space" disabled="false" data-v-429cfcf3="" data-v-1d22ad12="" data-v-c423d1fa="" style="margin-left: auto;">
          <button class="oxd-icon-button" type="button" data-v-f5c763eb="" data-v-1d22ad12="">
            <i class="oxd-icon bi-three-dots-vertical" data-v-bddebfba="" data-v-f5c763eb=""> </i>
          </button>
          <!---->
        </li>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is what I have tried so far, but doesnt work. It selects the checkboxes but not against all the criterias given below:

1- DIV, which contains the Requestor Name as Linda Jane Anderson
2- DIV, which contains Leave Type as CAN - Personal
3- DIV, which contains Leave Status as Pending Approval

This is how my XPATH looks like:

```
//div[contains(text(), "Linda Jane Anderson")]
/following::div[contains(text(), "CAN - Personal")]
/following::div[contains(text(),"Pending")]
/../preceding-sibling::div//input[@type="checkbox"]
```

Could you please help me writing an XPATH for it? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Linda Jane Anderson` should be `Anthony  Nolan` from your example you could use this XPath:

```
//div[@role='row']
    [div[@role='cell']/div[contains(text(),'Anthony Nolan')]]
    [div[@role='cell']/div[contains(text(),'CAN - Personal')]]
    [div[@role='cell']/div[contains(text(),'Pending')]]
    /div[@role='cell']//input[@type='checkbox']
```

Comment: Hello, Many thanks for the response. It didnt work unfortunately. I tried but didnt hit any records. Could you please take a look at it again?
Yup, I made a Typo in the Name, but you figured it right. Sorry about that!

Comment: I tested it against your example  and it worked.
Could you share more code?

Comment: Didnt work for me unfortunately. Regards to the Code, unfortunately thats all I have. But this is a Test Website, so If this suits you, I can give you the Leaves List Link.
https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/leave/viewLeaveList
To reach the above link, you would need to:
Login here(Credentials are mentioned on the page already):
https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/auth/login
and then click on the Leave List Symbol. That page shows the list of Vacations I am interested to select based on the Criteria mentioned above

Comment: It does work. But `Anthony Nolan` has not `CAN - Personal` but `CAN - Vacation`

Comment: Ach, sorry. My bad, it does work. Many thanks for the help. I didnt notice that and the Data changed in the meanwhile. Upvoted!